# Error with Asp.net MVC3 app after loading into Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I opened an existing ASP.NET MVC3 project that formerly worked just fine in a newly built machine with Visual Studio 2012 installed.

I'm now getting null exceptions in the following code.  After a User logs in, the following code is then executed to perform page fragment-level access.

The null exception is thrown on the WebViewPage.User object.  However, when in debug mode, I can actually inspect a real instance of the object (see image below)

```
 public static class WebViewPageExtensions
 {
      public static bool HasAccess(this WebViewPage pg)
        {
            if (pg == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("WebViewPage is null");
            if (pg.User == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("WebViewPage User is null");              
            return pg.User.IsInRole(User.ACCESS_LEVEL_A) || pg.User.IsInRole(User.ACCESS_LEVEL_B);
        }
 }
```

Note: this could be something with the way my environment is configured (web.config maybe?), but not really sure where to start.  As it is, the code that this is happening on is the same code running in production and the former developer environment.

All the references are still referring to the ASP.NET MVC3 version of the framework running on the .NET 4.0 platform.

[image: Inspecting the "null" pg.User object]

EDIT: Here's the callilng code from a Razer view:

```
 @if (this.HasAccess()) {                 
        <div>
                HTML here
        </div>  
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show the code that is calling HasAccess?

Comment: Added an edit above that has the HasAccess() call.  It's in a Razor template

Comment: Ok, and how about your controller action?  does the User object exist in the controller before you render the view?  And are you using a custom principal?

Comment: The User object is just the RolePrincipal. I can view it in the controller via HttpContext.User.

Comment: Well, there's nothing inherently wrong here.. so the problem must be somewhere else.  Unfortunately, these kinds of problems when you upgrade can be caused by things that are unrelated to the actual problem.  All you can do is start whittling down things until the problem goes away, then slowly adding things back until you discover the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks Mystere Man. I'm currently installing VS2010 to see if this can help.  I had already concluded the same you did, but hoping there's some magic voodoo that someone else already discovered.  Thanks.

Comment: I have problems with VS2012 with MVC4 and MVC3  Windows 7 as least I have no issues with MVC3 and zero with VS2010.  Windows 8 however seems to not let 4.0 framework run with VS2012.  I have been exciting about EF 5, TypeScript and all the new things in VS2012, but some of these things are too time consuming and frustrating to troubleshoot.  I will try to post a solution If I have your specific problem.  Definitely some bugs...

Comment: I tried installing VS2010 on this machine and ended up with the same problem.  I then went and did a fresh install of Win 7 and went straight to VS2010.  Everything now works as expected.  It seems installing VS2012 is the pain point.  (NOTE: I've simplified the experience that I've gone through to get it working again.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read section "Installing ASP.NET MVC 4 breaks ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM applications" from link http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253815. Follow setps "Required updates" to update your MVC 3 app.
 If you havent noticed, MVC4 gets installed with VS2012 and this is documented behavior.

Comment: Ok, this didn't originally work for me back when I tried it in October.  However, now in December, it seems to work in the Visual Studio 2012, Update 1.  Thanks.